Connect Postgresql database via Application Code on Ubuntu failed
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my laptop and installed PostgreSQL database 16.4. Then I configured to connect to database via Application code with Python. I did these steps:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 -y

After that, I verified that python3 was installed:
$ python3 --version
python 3.12.3

Then I typed this for PostgreSQL driver psycopg2:
#pip install psycopg2-binary
I got error message: external ly-managed-environment
Please advise how to install standard PostgreSQL driver and import psycopg2 correctly.

psycopg2 is in the standard repos.  sudo apt install python3-psycopg2
